# sending email to outside organization fails

Tags: exchange

we have `exchange 2013` in our organization, we want one client to use pop3 and smtp services from different location (but physicaly in our office). This computer has outlook configured with `smtp.other.com` and `pop3.other.com` . But when sending mail to anyone outside company he gets Server error: `550 Relay not permitted` . First of all I thought it is firewall issue. But it has no logs for this mail. 
I also added into accepted domain in exchange as an external relay, but it does not changed anything. Is this an exchange issue? Because I though if I'm sending email to outside smtp server it bypasses internal exchange. If it is a case where can i enable authentication for that outside mail in exchange?

Comment: Does send connector helps in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Send Connector has nothing to do with it.

You need to set the client to authenticate when sending, if you are using your Exchange server to send email. That will need to be in the format of domain\username .

However if you aren't using Exchange as the SMTP server, then you will need to enter the credentials for the SMTP server that you are using, unless you are using the SMTP server from your ISP.